# Is there a general term that covers both reading from and writing to memory?

Tags: memory, cpu

So the process of retrieving information from memory is referred to as a "read". And the process of storing information in memory is known as a "write"...

But, is there a term that covers *both* forms of memory access?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT HERE. Learn to turn your Caps Lock _off_.

Comment: Please don't yell. We can hear you just fine when you use your inside voice.

Comment: I ran a PHP script with `strtolower()` and there should be a new limit on Stack Exchange: 'No more than 10% of the post may be upper-case.'

Comment: @RADEK: BUT WHAT IF YOU'RE ASKING A COBOL QUESTION WITH LOTS OF CODE?

Comment: Are you by chance asking what the name of the combined "read and write" process is? We normally just call it "IO"

Comment: @oded or remap it to Ctrl to prevent an emacs-pinky.

Comment: @Matt solvage: 'No more than 10% of the post except for code may be upper-case.' or make a system that checks the tags, and looks at the percentage of upper-case text in all questions tagged that. Base it on that.

Comment: @dranchestern I/O, to be more exact.

Comment: @Radek No, then people start wrapping EVERYTHING in a code block.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H two things: this is the second comment today in reply to you, and see my updated comment. :)

Comment: @Radek: or remap it to Esc. It's much more useful than Ctrl in the best editor: vim :P

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: wait, who needs an editor anyway? [Real programmers use butterflies!](http://xkcd.com/378/)

Comment: Also, should be migrated to YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **I/O** - or **Input/Output**

Answer (score 1):

Might you be referring to the instruction cycle/fetch-execute cycle?

Typically:

1. Fetch the instruction
2. Decode the instruction
3. Execute the instruction
4. Store results

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle